# Speaker separation in recording using Google

Tags: speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm working on a project which has to do the following.

I've 4 users. when and the 4 users will talk the task is like this, the code by the end has to segregate/label/group the data based on the user's voice. I saw such feature available in IBM Watson and Azure. But I'm looking for something with in Google environment.

I'm able to get Speech to Text part done using the Speech API. But I want to segregate using any Google's API.

Please let me know how can I do it.

Comment: Google does not provide this feature yet.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284943/identifying-segments-when-a-person-is-speaking/8292994#8292994